# Apache Camel with Metro

Tags: java, jax-ws, apache-camel, java-metro-framework

Apache Camel comes with components for CXF and Axis webservice frameworks. Is there a camel-metro component too ? It would be rather limiting if there was no such component, since JDK 7 comes with JAX-WS RI and a lot of projects use the Metro webservice stack.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel comes with Apache CXF and Spring-WS components out of the box.

- http://camel.apache.org/cxf
- http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

There is **no** Axis or Metro components.

Though as its all just Java code you can use Metro and call Camel etc.
We have an old tutorial on how to integrate Apache Axis 1.4 with Camel: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-axis-camel.html

Though at Apache we love contributions. So if anyone is up for creating a camel-metro component then that would be great. We have a guide how to create new components here: http://camel.apache.org/add-new-component-guide.html

And you can read about contributing here: http://camel.apache.org/contributing.html

Comment: Thankd you for your reply. What Camel component do you suggest to use for integration with Metro ?

Answer (score 0):

As of today there is no camel metor framework available.